# SyntaxError in while loop or input of my dice program in Python

Tags: python, dice

To learn and master the fundaments of python I made a dice program, but now that I finished it says that there is an syntax error and I don't understand what the error is. Can you help me out?
I have searched for it but do really not understand were the mistake is.

```
import random
x = random.randrange(10, 20, 1)
print(x)

y = input("roll again?")
while y = "yes":
    continue
    print(x)
else :
    print("thanks for using my app!")
    continue
    break
```

Comment: can you share the error on your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Your variable `y` will always be `yes` if it was use for the first time. Also, I believe the error happens because you are using `break` and `continue` in else statement (while you actually can not).

I think what you are trying to do is like this:

```py
import random
y = "yes" #set y to be yes by default

while y == "yes": # use == instead of =
    x = random.randrange(10, 20, 1)
    print(x)

    y = input("roll again?")
    #you do not need to use continue/break here
else :
    print("thanks for using my app!")
```

Comment: Now I have this: EOFError: EOF when reading a line. It is about y = input("roll again?"). I'm working on Atom, maybe it doesn't support input().

Comment: @Omni-P Are you running python 2 or 3?

Comment: Although it worked fine with me, you may need to use str() around input: `str(input("roll again?"))`